# How to remove invisible bedrock in MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was inside of a huge build me and my friend made on MCPE. I was messing around with inventory editing and accidentally placed invisible bedrock on the floor in the middle of the build.

Is there any way to fix this?

I am willing to do pretty much anything to fix it.

I am on MCPE on IOS, and I can transfer MCPE worlds off of it.

Comment: I don't know much about PE version(Because i play PC) but if you have access to the **/fill** command you can go in your rooms and **/fill** the insides of them with air. also if you are playing in creative can you not just delete the invisible bedrock every time you run in to it.

Comment: Sadly, MCPE doesn't have commands, and sadly you can't even look at the block. You place and break straight through it.

Comment: But you can't walk through it(i'm guessing although i've never heard about invisible bedrock, unless you mean barrier block) so why can't u just delete it everytime you run into it. if you can't walk forward just rapid click until you delete the invisible bedrock in front of you

Comment: Because your hand goes straight through it, sadly. It's like barrier block, but you place and break the blocks behind it when you try to destroy it :/

Comment: So its impossible to delete?

Comment: I don't know. I'm pretty sure ingame, so I probably need an external program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40801/discussion-between-scratchywon-and-gamer103).

Comment: Are u coming or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use [WorldEdit PE](http://mcpedl.com/worldedit-pe/)  mod for removing the invisible bedrock. Just replace blocks in its plane with air blocks.

I believe this is only available for android. However, as you can transfer the world, this should not be a problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I just fixed it. I ended up using SPC, but this is really the correct answer!

Comment: Who did that downvote?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove invisible bedrock. I have tried everything I could on my mcpe server I have on plug pe. I used to have a map of the server and I surrounded it with invisible bedrock cause I thought you couldn't break anything behind it, but now I have redone my spawn and can't remove the bedrock and have no choice now but to start a new world. I have tried everything I could. I'm sorry but its true. You can lower the floor in the room you placed it in until you don't step into the bedrock.

Answer (score 0):

I have mcpe on my phone, so I use the rapid build feature in mcpe master. All I do is make the app build a small line throught the invisible block, then break the line.

Answer (score -2):

i escape by Invisible bedrock In two commands:
I Set spawnpoit on/under invisible bedrock  (cordonates is on spawn point!) 
II say in cheat /setblock (cordonates) planks Exemple !
IF dont know, is my idea for pc for cordonates. But I know so minecraft at 11 years
you dont know as a genius in minecraft, sorry But this is working %100 for my experience ! If dont work a block to set try up or down to set cordonates!
 ex `11 is Y` is your head at block try under as 10 or 9 because the situation!
Need to post on youtube At minecraft pocket edition this with the link! 
Need To try (please read  to the end is working 100% no ploblems are you read)
 Message come from Romania! Sended at 21:43 06 07 2018 
                                          day | mount | year